# How to insert current full date with day in a field inside a td when select it and click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to inset full date in a field when click in the bottom, however i cant get it to work.

i have the fallowing code.

```js
$(
    function(){
        let lastFocusEl=null;
        
        $('#date').click(function(){
                  var time = new Date();                     
                  if(lastFocusEl) lastFocusEl.value = time.toTimeString();  
        });
        
        let f = function() { lastFocusEl=this};
        $('#input_62[]').focus(f);
        $('#input_62[]').focus(f);
        $('#input_62[]').focus(f);

    }  
);


may be useful code 

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
return date;
}


var date = new Date();

alert(date.addDays(5));
```

```html
<td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_62_cell1" data-label="DEPARTED"><input type="text" name="input_62[]" value=""></td>

<td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_62_cell2" data-label="DEPARTED"><input type="text" name="input_62[]" value=""></td>

<td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_62_cell3" data-label="DEPARTED"><input type="text" name="input_62[]" value=""></td>

<td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_62_cell4" data-label="DEPARTED"><input type="text" name="input_62[]" value=""></td>

<input type="button" value="DATE" name="DATE" id="DATE">
```

Comment: "logically" talking, your code seems to be trying to assign the time value to the **last** focused element. This is quite different from your current question _i want to inset full date in a field when click in the bottom_. Is it the intended behavior?

Comment: this is the code that i was able to put together somehow someone in the community will know how to fix it. thanks for the help.

Comment: Well... The question is whether you wanted it to act in this way. Your question is different from what the code is meant to be currently doing: do you want it to select the **last focused element** or the first available item? or all the items?

Comment: correct, the last focused element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firsly, `id`'s are case-sensitive, so `$('#date')` will not find `<input id="DATE">`... you need to either change the `id` or the selector.

`$('#input_62[]')` will not work, because `#` is used for the `id` of an element, not the `name`.

So you can either use the following selector...

```
$('input[name="input_62[]"]')
```

Or instead, give the `<input>` controls a class and use that instead which would be my preference...

```js
$(function(){
    let lastFocusEl=null;

    $('#DATE').click(function(){
        var time = new Date();                     
        if(lastFocusEl) lastFocusEl.value = time.toTimeString();  
    });

    let f = function() { lastFocusEl=this};
    $('.input_62').focus(f);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_62_cell1" data-label="DEPARTED"><input type="text" class="input_62" name="input_62[]" value=""></td>

<td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_62_cell2" data-label="DEPARTED"><input type="text" class="input_62" name="input_62[]" value=""></td>

<td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_62_cell3" data-label="DEPARTED"><input type="text" class="input_62" name="input_62[]" value=""></td>

<td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_62_cell4" data-label="DEPARTED"><input type="text" class="input_62" name="input_62[]" value=""></td>

<input type="button" value="DATE" name="DATE" id="DATE">
```

Comment: works like a champ! thanks, anyway to also get the day in the time field?

Comment: You're welcome. I'd recommend checking out [datejs](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs) which provides a huge amount of functionality